# SSRS Sum Column

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a report table

I have rows called 'department'

I have a column 'measurement'

I have expression of =Avg(Fields!measurement.Value)

what I wish to do is total row of the below (bottom of column) of the measurement column. This to sum / total of the averages at the end for all the departments.

I cannot seem to get this to work. I have right clicked on the table, and added a total, but it does not sum the averages.

something like =sum(Avg(Fields!measurement.Value))

Any ideas team please

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea if it works but if I were you, I would try to do the sum based on the textbox.
Try something like this code : `=Sum(ReportItems!<textboxName>.Value)`
You have to change  with the name of the textbox where you put your expression `=Avg(Fields!measurement.Value)`

Comment: no joy sorry. I even tried renaming the text box, no joy

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you have a row group called 'department' then you can simply set the expression in your total row to ...

```
=Sum(Avg(Fields!measurement.Value, "department"))
```

What this does is take the average within in 'department' scope (in your case the rowgroup is the scope) and then simply sums those values.

**Note: the scope is case sensitive** It must match your rowgroup name exactly.

Comment: no joy sorry , not a valid aggregate function. please help

Comment: Please update your question showing the report design, including any row and column groups. Also show any existing expressions and  finally show where you want this new calculation to appear. The answer I gave does work if the row groups are set up as they commonly are.